# filter data of NSArry from plist

Tags: iphone

I want to filter data by city wise and print it into table section wise.
I have code like this.

```
NSMutableArray *key1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
NSMutableArray *city=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
NSMutableArray *name= [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
for(id key in data) {
    [key1 addObject:key];
}
for (int i=0;i<[key1 count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"key:%@",[key1 objectAtIndex:i]);
}
for (int i=0;i<[key1 count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *email_key=[data objectForKey:[key1 objectAtIndex:i]];
    [city addObject:[email_key objectForKey:@"city"]]; 
    [name addObject:[email_key objectForKey:@"f_name"]];
}
```

I have array of city that are from plist.

My Plist's content:

```
<key>bh@gmail.com</key>
<dict>
    <key>fnmae</key><string>hello</string>
    <key>city</key><string>DElhi</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>fnmae</key><string>hi</string>
    <key>city</key><string>Bombay</string>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get all unique city's name as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary *cityBasedData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for(id key in data) {
    [key1 addObject:key];
}
for (int i=0;i<[key1 count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *email_key=[data objectForKey:[key1 objectAtIndex:i]];
    if (![cityBasedData objectForKey:[email_key objectForKey:@"city"]]) {
     NSMutableArray *nameList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [nameList addObject:[email_key objectForKey:@"f_name"]];
     [cityBasedData setValue:nameList forKey:[email_key objectForKey:@"city"]];
     [nameList release]; 
    }
    else
    {
      NSMutableArray *nameList = [cityBasedData objectForKey:[email_key objectForKey:@"city"]];
      [nameList addObject:[email_key objectForKey:@"f_name"]];
     [cityBasedData setValue:nameList forKey:[email_key objectForKey:@"city"]];
    }

}
```

After getting this dictionary, you can traverse each key in the dictionary and get array for each key:

```
for(id key in cityBasedData)
{
   //get array as follows:
   NSArray *namelist = [cityBasedData objectForKey:key];
}
```

Comment: It will use to display data in table cell.But when click on table cell that navigate to another xib and in that i have to display data for that user.And for that i have to pass key to next xib.How can i pass value of that cell to another xib?

Comment: How to display data in table with section wise of city?